# Rails 5.0 and JQuery .dialog() Not Working

Tags: jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-5, jquery-rails

I'm upgrading a rails app from `4.2` to `5.0`. The ruby version is `2.6.4`

The app has a view that allows the user to click a link to run a scheduling script that assigns students into courses/classes.  The script can take several minutes to run to completion, so we show a modal dialog box that, like a progress-bar, shows where the process is currently at.  But in the `rails 5.0` version, this is not working. There is no error(s), just the popup is not appearing. I figured it was a JQuery thing, so using try/catch blocks, I found it is in the `.dialog(...)` call.  But I'm not sure why it is failing.  I believe I have the correct `JQuery` gems and the assets/files set up correctly for rails 5.0.

```
Gemfile:
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
...
```

```
Gemfile.lock:
...
jquery-rails (4.4.0)
  rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
  railties (>= 4.2.0)
  thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
jquery-ui-rails (6.0.1)
  railties (>= 3.2.16)
...
```

```
app/assets/application.js:
...
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui/widgets/dialog
//= require_tree .
```

```
app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
...
*= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 *= require jquery-ui
 *= require jquery-ui/dialog
```

The popup form:

```
app/views/elements/_scheduling_dialog_popup.html.erb:
<%
  # This partial will attach a Jquery event to a submit button that will display a modal-screen 
  # during the (potentially) long scheduling process.
%>
<% content_for :head do %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("a#autoschedule").click(function() {
      JQuery('div#import_modal_box').dialog({bgiframe: true, modal: true, width:450, draggable: false, closeOnEscape: false, resizable: false}); 
    });
  });
  </script>
<% end %>
<div id="import_modal_box" style="display:none;">
  <p style="float:left;margin-right:1em;"><%= image_tag 'ajax-loader.gif' %></p>
  <h3>Auto Class Assignment for <%= pluralize(Student.count,'student') %></h3>
  <p>There are <%= pluralize(ClassTime.sum(:enrollment_limit),'spot') %> available in <%= pluralize(ClassTime.count,'class') %> for <%= pluralize(UpcomingCourse.count,'course')%>.</p><p>This may take a few minutes, please wait.</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

I've read through the docs at: [ruby-docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/jquery-ui-rails/5.0.5).  I see I only need to use `//= require jquery-ui` to require everything , but I added the `//= require jquery-ui/widgets/dialog` just to be sure.

What am I missing to get this to work?

Thanks for any advise.

Comment: what is `bgiframe`? I do not see this as an option: https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: I actually removed the `bigiframe: true`, but it made no difference.  To answer your question, with what little I've found on it is "I think" it has something to do with getting things to work in IE6.  Since we no longer work to support IE6, I removed that code.  But I could be wrong :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was "finally" able to resolve this issue. It actually had nothing to do with the dialog() function, directly.  I brought up the Developer Tools and ran the Console tab/window to see if I was getting any errors or warnings and found I had a ton of `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined ....` errors.  After some searching I found that Rails 5.2 does not need `jquery_ujs`, so I removed the `//= require jquery_ujs` line from my `assets/javascripts/application.js` file.  Now it works.